# Debugging gradle build file that uses Kotlin DSL

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

Is it possible to debug a gradle build file that is written using Kotlin DSL? A google search doesn't really show anything. By debugging, I'm really talking about using breakpoints that let you step into the gradle file and execute each line and inspect variables.

Comment: I guess technically you could pass JVM args to the JVM used by Gradle to setup a debug agent, but I'm not sure whether the IDE will be able to integrate with it via its UI (editor/breakpoints/debug panel etc)

Comment: Mmmh actually if you run a Gradle run configuration from your IDE, can't you just use it as a Debug configuration?

Comment: @Johann
I'm not sure if this is possible or at least i don't know, however you can add logs to your DSL code and check the result at the console.
You can create logs via `println` function for example.